# Dojo Select widget not populating contents from a datastore

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have been trying to connect to simply connect a datastore (ItemFileReadStore) to a dijit.form.Select widget and have been unable to.  If I use the options field to populate it then the widget works fine but when I go to use the store field to populate it the widget appears but its contents are empty. The code that I am trying to use is below:

```
  var readStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
                            label: "label",
                            identifier: "value",
                            //items: nestedSortOptions1
                            items: [{label : "Lab1", value: "Val1"}]
                    });
  var sel1 = new dijit.form.Select({
                    id:"sel1",
                    name: "sel1",
                    required: true,
                    style: "width: 170px;",
                    //options: nestedSortOptions1
                    store: readStore
            },"sel1");
```

I assumed that you would make this widget "data-enabled" using the store field but I may be mistaken. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track, but in the case of your particular example posted, there are two problems:

Firstly, the properties you're passing to ItemFileReadStore should be further embedded inside a `data` attribute, i.e.:

```
var readStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
    data: {
        label: "label",
        identifier: "value",
        items: [
            { label: "Lab1", value: "Val1" }
        ]
    }
});
```

(See explanation of the data attribute on the reference guide page for ItemFileReadStore: http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html)

Secondly, you're neglecting to call `sel1.startup()` after instantiating the Select.  Turns out `startup` is precisely where the Select fetches from the store.

(The `startup` method is called automatically in instances where you rely on `dojo.parser` to parse HTML-declared widget instances; it's also called automatically on child widgets of layout widgets when the layout widget's `startup` is called.)

Comment: Thanks especially for the startup tip, one of those things that is so easy to overlook.